# Parsing Google Stock XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, parsing

I've spent a silly amount of time trying to figure this out, but at this point it's driving me insane. I'm trying to parse the XML for Google's unofficial stock api like this: http://www.google.com/ig/api?stock=GOOG

I've never dealt with XML that uses only attributes, so I don't know if that's what's making me completely useless at figuring this out. I'm pulling in the XML via a simple PHP snippet, then attempting to parse it using jQuery.parse().

```
<script>
    var xml = '<? echo get_url_contents('www.google.com/ig/api?stock=GOOG'); ?>',
        xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
        $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
        $title = $xml.find( "last" );

    /* append stock value to #goog */
    $( "#goog" ).append( $this.attr($title) );
</script>
```

Am I just completely on the wrong track here? Any guidance would be fantastic.

Comment: You need to Javascript-escape the XML.

Comment: @SLaks Actually, if you look at the XML he is fetching, it is safe to include there.

Comment: @DanielBrockman: For this particular stock.  If an attacker can get a stock listed, he has an XSS hole.

Comment: What do you expect `$this` to be?  It's not defined anywhere.

Comment: @SLaks OK, OK, good point. (I mean, I wouldn’t just dump it out like that either, I just thought it sounded like you meant that was the problem.)

Comment: This was just an exercise to try and deal with the XML. I won't be using this in production or anything for now, but thank you for the advice! $this was left over from a previous attempt at fixing it. >.<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s what that last line would look like:

```
$("#goog").text($title.attr("data"))
```

(Although I’m not sure why the variable holding the `<last>` element is called `$title`?)

Comment: Gah I should have cleaned everything up first before posting it. Originally I was pulling out multiple things, then focused on one for debugging. For some reason I can now view the value if I call it in an alert, but not in #goog! I think I can figure it out now, though. Thank you for your help!